# Entity Framework - cannot generate database from my EDMX because new entities are not in database?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, poco

Having got a chunk of my application working with Entity Framework 4.1, I needed to add a couple more tables. I created the entities and associations in the Model Viewer and then ask it to generate the database from the model.

Immediately I get a selection of validation errors and a pop-up informs me that I must clear all validation errors before I can generate the database.

The errors in question are all along the lines of:

> Error 11007: Entity type 'EntityName' is not mapped.

Or

> Error 11008: Association 'AssociationName' is not mapped.

I get this error once for each new Entity and Association I have created.

Now I get that they are not mapped to the database yet, this seems quite logical as they are totally new to the model. That is why I'm trying to use the "Generate Database From Model" tools to generate the database.

Am I understanding correctly that I cannot generate a new database from the model because the new Entities and Associations I have added to the Model are not already in the database? If so, how do I work around this?

Comment: If all that's wrong is unmapped associations and entities, "generate database from model" should work, and I've used it that way myself. Are you sure all your errors are about yet-unmapped entities, or might there be one real error hidden in a list of dozens of ignorable errors?

Comment: Aha! A sneaky little association that I had deleted in the editor but it had somehow not properly deleted from the .EDMX file hidden away there. Good tip @hvd. Any chance of reworking that comment as an answer?

Comment: I'd be happy to, but if you can recall what you did to get the error (how specifically you deleted the association), it would be more useful if you answer your question yourself and put that in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It transpired that ( as suggested in comments by hdv ) there was another error in the .EDMX file which was being lost amongst the Error Message noise. This related to a field that I had used to key an association and later deleted without realising that the association depended on it.

The error message included a line in the .EDMX file so I closed it in the Model Editor and used `Open With > XML Editor` to open the source, find the relevant line and delete the association. This flagged up a few more errors where that association was referenced from elsewhere and after removing those I could open the file in Model Viewer again and it allowed me to create the database.

Comment: +1: Worked for me. You can also delete the faulty associations from the designer interface. Just select the association line and delete. :)

Comment: Sometimes, but in my case I had already deleted them from the designer view but they were still hidden away in the xml document for reasons known only to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Error 11007: Entity type 'EntityName' is not mapped can also be caused by a left over class file (e.g. `entityname.cs`) in your solution folder...

I faced this same problem: `Error 11007: Entity type 'EntityName' is not mapped.` in VS2010 using TFS. I believe it was likely caused by using copy and paste and other edits of new entities in the designer. Even undoing changes in TFS, closing down VS2010 etc. didn't work.

On investigation, even though I had rolled back to the last checked in version in TFS, when viewing the source folder (containing the .edmx file) I discovered an `entityname.cs` file which related to the offending entity I had been trying to add, had then deleted and recreated. This could also be seen using the 'Show All Files' feature in the VS2010 Solution Explorer.

Once the offending file had been deleted, the EDMX could be edited. Once the database schema has been updated to match, we no longer got the error when using Update Model from Database (which we do in order to reference Custom SQL Functions etc. - somewhat O/T I know).

I hope this helps someone else experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open edmx in xml editor and check if AssociationSetMapping exists for your association.